# How to find which properties are available for getByRole different elements?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, accessibility, react-testing-library

When writing unit tests with React Testing Library, we can access elements by their role with `getByRole`.

For example, if the element is `heading`, it has `level` option:

```
const headingNode = screen.getByRole('heading', { level: 3 });
```

Or if it's `radio` it has `name`:

```
 const radioNode = screen.getByRole('radio', { name: 'high'});
```

My question is, where can be found all the possible options for each type?
Is there a documentation for this? Didn't find it.

Answer (score 5):

It is described in the documentation of the corresponding query:

> Here you can see [a table of HTML elements with their default and desired roles](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance).

https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/byrole#api